# SSIS - Set SQL query result to variable for Excel connection string

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I want to set connection string using SQL Query result from my table. I need to import excel file from certain folder every month but i need to import only latest file name (FILE_YYYYMMDD)

Here is my table

[image: Here is my table]

I already follow some instruction using Execute SQL Task to get the result of the query and i want to assign the result as connection string to import excel file since the folder will get new file every month.

Here is my variable and my Result Set in Execute SQL Task
[image: Execute SQL Task Editor]
[image]

I want to make FilePath with max FileDate as Excel connection string in SSIS.

Is there anyway to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a business reason the files have to stay put in the folder? It's not uncommon for ETL processes to have Pickup, Processing and Complete folders (or similarly named) with the files moving between them at each stage.

Comment: Yep I thought the same, but yes there is some reason the file will append in the folder, but with different last name (YYYYMMDD)

Comment: You can just select the `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY FileDate DESC` to get the latest `FilePath` in your SQL Task.

Comment: I want to assign it as variable for connection string

Comment: Make sure you set your SQL Task `Result Set` to `Single Row`. This will allow you to use it as the desired variable value.

Comment: I already set it as `Single Row` but when I tried to pass it as excel connection string, the result is not what i expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be like below :

> ```
> CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID INT, FileName VARCHAR(255),FileDate DATE)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO MyTable(ID,FileName,FileDate) VALUES
> (5,'C:\Users\Public\Documents\File_20200130.xls','2020-01-30'),
> (5,'C:\Users\Public\Documents\File_20200131.xls','2020-01-31'),
> (5,'C:\Users\Public\Documents\File_20220301.xls','2022-03-01')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT FileName FROM MyTable
> WHERE FileDate = (SELECT MAX(FileDate) FROM MyTable )
> ```

> ```
> | FileName                                    |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | C:\Users\Public\Documents\File_20220301.xls |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87f1cd90178c90981e4bb1750fd61ea6)*

Create a variable for the value we need to pass, the in the Execute SQL Task component, put the query mentioned above that returns the path with the max value of the date. Please make sure to set the result set to single row.

Then go to the variables tab and add the variable there.

**To store the `FileName` as variable and use it as connection string for Excel source :**

Select the `Connection Manager`, and in the `Properties` window, you will find the Expressions entry where you can use/concatenate the variable(s) in the ConnectionString entity.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I try it and you need to make sure the DelayValidation in properties is FALSE to skip the validation of dynamic variable CMIIW